# Perform different actions with predefined probability based on random value between 0 and 99

Tags: c++, math, random, arduino, probability

I'm working on a project where I run actions randomly with a certain probability.

I basically have four actions. `Action A` has a probability of 40%, `Action B` has a probability of 40%, `Action C` has a probability of 15% and `Action D` has a probability of 5%.

My approach was to generate a random number (int) between 0 and 99 (100 possible integer values). Then run the actions accordingly, but the numbers don't add up for me.

The code is basically:

```
    // values starting from 0 up to 99
    randNumber=random(100);

    // Probability of 40% (will enter for values including 59 up to 99 (40 numbers))
    if (randNumber >= 59)
    {
      actionA();
    }
    // Probability of 40% (will enter for values including 18 up to 58 (40 numbers))
    else if (randNumber >=18)
    {
      actionB();
    }
    // Probability of 15% (will enter for values including 2 up to 17 (15 numbers))
    else if (randNumber >=2)
    {
      actionC();
    }
    // Remaining probability of what should be 5% (will enter for values including 0 to 1 (2 numbers)) ???
    else
    {
        actionD();
    }
```

Where am I going wrong? With values from 0 to 99, I should have 100 possible numbers. However, the last probability of the last 5% does not add up.

Source of random(): https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/random-numbers/random/

Comment: Source of `random(100);` please.

Comment: not possible to answer without knowing what `random(100)` is and how you add up the probabilities and determine that they are off. Please read about [mcve]

Comment: How do the two choices 0 or 1 make 5% out of 100? Your intervals are 41, 41, 16, and 2 numbers wide.

Comment: The values `59` through `99` is a range of **41** numbers.  Likewise, `18` through `58` is also 41 numbers and `2` through `17` is 16 values.  If `random(100)` really is uniform [0,99], you will get a value less than `2` 2% of the time, not 5%.

Comment: Instead of `59`, `18` and `2`, you should be using the numbers `60`, `20` and `5`.

Comment: Sorry about the missing detail about the random function, I've added a reference of the function in use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually depends on the source of random(int) function, you are not showing on your question, but I think your problem is more math-related than C++-related, if actually random(int) is uniform between 0 and 99 included.

How many are >=59? I am quite sure there are 41, not 40, therefore you are giving a probability equal to 41%, not 40% (99 - 59 + 1 for the `>=`). And `18<= x < 59` is quite the same, there actually are 41.

At the end of the day, you do not have numbers because every interval is 1 too much.

Try removing the equal from that `>=` and rethink about your intervals accordingly, (59, 19 and so on)

Answer (score 3):

As chiappar mentioned it is a math problem, not a code problem.
But his solution is wrong.

To solve this you could remove the equal sign from `>=`, but then you also have to update the values, so they will be as follows:

1. `if (randNumber > 59)`
2. `if (randNumber >19)`
3. `if (randNumber >4)`
4. `else`

Comment: Note that meanwhile, chiappar has edited their answer in order to fix it. Therefore, you may want to check whether your claim that their answer is wrong is still correct, and if not, you may want to [edit] your answer to remove that claim.